# Invite People with the Facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-group

Good Morning,
I'm a bit desperate...
I try to invite people to a group where I'm the Admin of the Group.
With a get me/friends. I get a List of Users. There have an ID. This ID I try to Use for invite People. 
For trying I use the https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer. 
So If I do a "Post" with groupID/members and the Param Member and the Value an User ID from my friendlist with "IDFromFriendlist" then I get every time this error Message. `"message": "(#100) \"4\" does not resolve to a valid user ID",`.

Have someone a Idea what I Do wrong?

Ps. The Number is changed to protect the Account of my friend

Thank you for your Help.
Kind Regards,
Florian

Comment: There is no way to invite people to a group

Comment: But the function is described in the api documentation. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.8/group/members
@WizKid

Comment: So you read it? "Apps can invite people (if they are an admin, developer, or tester of the app) to a group created by that app"

Comment: Hmm  i haven't read this sentence:/ this is bad...  thank you

Comment: No it is good. It means people can't spam their friends with group invites

Comment: Sure. But one of my people of my network has a company. Hey bought a product where is included the membership in a Facebook group. There are now over 2 thousand people. Is a many work for the support to manage this users. I want automize this process for him. In the feature I think it's over 10 thousand people...

Comment: They shouldn't have promised something they couldn't do

Comment: They can do it. But is many work for the support of this company.